# Como estilizar links e imagens que estão referenciados em HTTP e não em HTTPS?

Tags: html5, css3, http, https

Eu tenho várias páginas com várias imagens e vários links. Porém estou migrando do protocolo `HTTP` para o `HTTPS`. Gostaria que todas as imagens e links que fossem com indexados ou linkados via HTTP aparecessem com uma borda vermelha ou com o texto em vermelho.

Por exemplo, se o link for http a cor fica vermelha, se a imagem for http coloca uma borda vermelha:

```
<a href="http://google.com">link http</a>     <!-- vermelho -->
<a href="https://google.com">link https</a>   <!-- cor normal -->

<img src="http://imagem.com" >   <!-- borda vermelha -->
<img src="https://imagem.com">   <!-- sem borda -->
```

**Como eu poderia fazer essa estilização de CSS nesses elementos caso sejam referenciados via HTTP?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O seletor `src*="http://"` é incorreto para isto, pois o `*=` indica que vai buscar em qualquer **lugar do atributo**, o seletor correto a se usar seria o `^=`, os seletores CSS2.1/2.2 para atributos são os seguintes:

- `[data-foo^="bar"]` começa com o valor definido
- `[data-foo$="bar"]` termina com o valor definido
- `[data-foo*="bar"]` contém o valor (independente de ser começo, meio e fim)
- `[data-foo~="bar"]` faz o comportamento ser semelhante ao do seletor de classes, ou seja o `"bar"` é o valor que será avaliado entre os espaços, exemplo:

  ```
  <div data-foo="foo bar baz"></div> <!-- será pego pelo seletor -->
  <div data-foo="foo bar bar"></div> <!-- será pego pelo seletor -->
  <div data-foo="bar foo baz"></div> <!-- será pego pelo seletor -->
  <div data-foo="a b c"></div> <!-- NÃO será pego pelo seletor -->
  <div data-foo="a bar c"></div> <!-- será pego pelo seletor -->
  ```
- `[data-foo|="bar"]` este seletor é usado **geralmente** para pegar que representam idiomas, pois ele buscará elementos como:

  ```
  <div data-foo="bar"></div>
  <div data-foo="bar-baz"></div>
  ```

  Ou seja, deve ser exatamente `"bar"` ou deve começar com `bar-`, um uso com elementos indicados em português (e variantes):

Então como já disse no começo, para pegar atributos que comecem com `http://` o correto seria usar `^=` assim:

```css
a[href^="http://"] {
     color: red;
}

img[src^="http://"] {
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com">link http</a> <br>
<a href="https://google.com">link https</a> <hr>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UVKr.jpg" alt="imagem com http"> <br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UVKr.jpg" alt="imagem com https">
```

---

Agora imagine que a sua imagem tenha uma URL dinamica assim:

```
<img src="http://site.com/ptoxy.php?url=https://foobarbaz.com/imagem.jpg">
```

Se usar o CSS assim:

```
img[src*="https://"] {
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Vai ser aplicado a essa imagem, **quando não deveria**

**Fonte:** https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: Valeu mestre []'s

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar seletores de atributo.

```
/* elementos <a> onde o href inicia com "http://"  */
a[href^="http://"] {
    color: red;
}

/* elementos <img> onde o src inicia com "http://"  */
img[src^="http://"] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda jovem, mas optei pela outra resposta tudo bem. Abs